# wp7: how to detect Listbox on screen visualized item?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scroll

In my application there is one Listbox and one  textblock both are coupled inside a scrollviewer. Means I want to scroll both listbox and textblock together (following XAML  may explain better ).  I want to show some text in textblock from listbox which item is currently visible on screen.  So I have to know which item is currently visible on screen.

Right now I have no clue what to do. Any suggestion or comment is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

```
<ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

  <StackPanel>

    <ListBox x:Name="myListBox"  SelectionChanged="SelectinoChanged" Height="150">
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation ="Horizontal" >
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
              <TranslateTransform X="0"/>
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
          </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="30"/>
            <Button Content="{Binding name}" FontSize="30" Name="but" Click="but_Click"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <TextBlock Name="tb" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="40" Height="50" />

  </StackPanel>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Listbox contains a ScrollViewer in it.

so you should just remove your ScrollViewer !

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="myListBox>
        ...
    </ListBox>
    <TextBlock Name="tb"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and maybe set on the ListBox

```
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

Comment: If I remove Scrollviewer how do I scroll Textbock. I have to scroll both Listbox and TextBlock together. There is no property in ListBox HorizontalScrollBarVisibility. Can somebody else give me some right way to complete my task. Or is it possible at all?